# What is this Beechcraft bonanza A36 wing feature?

Tags: wing, feature-identification, beechcraft-bonanza

can someone explain what is this thing on leading edge of bonanza A36 aircraft.
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 14):

The feature is a [dual vortex generator](https://aeroresourcesinc.com/uploads/198306-1983%20Beech%20B36TC%20Bonanza.pdf) added to both wings to improve spin characteristics, which did not meet certification standards after the wings were lengthened to increase range by adding fuel capacity. These work opposite to stall strips; they keep airflow attached to the wing ahead of the ailerons. The vortex generated blocks the stall from the wing root from reaching the ailerons so that control is maintained in a spin, thereby allowing recovery in the required one turn.

> The device, a dual vortex generator, resulted from Beech's efforts to improve the airplane's spin characteristics. During initial tests, the company found that the B36TC, with its long and heavy wings, would enter a rapid, nose-high spin to the right when loaded to aft-CG.

[image]

Comment: @Pilothead-- was trying to figure out from pics how far outboard it was attached--

Comment: @quietflyer If they were smaller and inboard they would have been stall strips.